# For what purpose is the .docker directory used?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Recently, in one project, I encountered such a situation that docker compose when deploying refers to the ".docker" directory. I wanted to read more about this approach, but did not find the information. Tell me please, what is the docker-compose and ".docker" stack?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean the one in your `$HOME`? It stores some per-user configs, like authentication credentials to registries.

Comment: How does docker-compose access the .docker directory?

Comment: If it's going to pull images, maybe? Or if your question is about the permissions, `docker-compose` is not much different from original `docker` command. They're both command line interfaces to talk with docker daemon.